# How do I find my b64secret from GDAX API?

Tags: api, gdax

How did I find the b64secret that is automatically generated by GDAX API? I have a passphrase and API key that I got from GDAX, but I don't know what/where the b64secret is. The documentation says that the secret will be randomly generated and provided to me. I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node#the-authenticated-api-client) and also the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862777/gdax-node-b64secret), but the answer did not help and only directed me to the documentation. I hit create keys but I never saw the secret.

So for someone that has actually done this before, how do I find/get the b64secret?

I originally asked on SO but it wasn't answered, and I didn't find the same question after a very brief search on here.